# Как показать содержимое уведомления в Activity

Tags: firebase, push-уведомления, push

Всем привет,вопрос такой,[по данному уроку](https://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/),подключил уведомления с изображениями через топик.
Как заставить приложение при нажатии на уведомление открыть активити с текстом и изображением уведомления.Раньше видел такой урок в интернете но не могу сейчас найти почему-то.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопрос решился через Intent put/get
Таким образом из **MyFirebaseMessagingService.java**
`Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, PushTest.class);
        resultIntent.putExtra("title", title);
        resultIntent.putExtra("message", message);
        resultIntent.putExtra("iconUrl", iconUrl);`

Передаем данные в **PushTest.java**

```
        txtTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
    txtMessage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtMessage);
    textView5  = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);
    imageView2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
    Intent resultIntent = getIntent();

    String title = resultIntent.getStringExtra("title");
    String message = resultIntent.getStringExtra("message");
    String iconUrl = resultIntent.getStringExtra("iconUrl");
    txtTitle.setText(title);
    txtMessage.setText(message);
    textView5.setText(iconUrl);
    Picasso.get().load(iconUrl).placeholder(R.drawable.imn).into(imageView2);
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, старайтесь писать более развёрнутые ответы, сопровождая их примерами кода - это может помочь кому-то в будущем)

Comment: Все готово,добавил код)Спасибо за совет